# Azure Web App loses permissions on a keyvault secret when a new secret version is added

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-webapps

My .NET6 web app uses keyvault secret references in its configuration.
The references are set like this:
`@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://myapp.vault.azure.net/secrets/My--Secret)`

The app is being deployed using Release pipelines. Deployment also gives the app access to the keyvault using the app's AD identity (using legacy RM for now):

```
$servicePrincipalId = $(Get-AzureRmADServicePrincipal -DisplayName $servicePrincipalName).Id

Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName $keyVaultName -ObjectId $servicePrincipalId
```

Everything works fine after the app is deployed. It also survives restarting without issues.

However, when I add a new version to a referenced secret and restart the web app, it shows access errors for that specific key:

```
Key Vault reference was not able to be resolved because site was denied access to Key Vault reference's vault.
```

I tried multiple things:

- restart the app a few times - doesn't help
- rerun the Powershell script - doesn't help
- manually remove the app from keyvault access policies, restart (ok - all references show red), manually add the app back to keyvault access policies - all references are green again, except the one that I modified
- redeploy the app's files - doesn't help
- redeploy the app through Azure resource group deployment task - it works!

To summarise, the only way to give the app the permissions to the modified keyvault secret, is to redeploy the app.

I could reliably reproduce the issue in two Azure subscriptions with two instances of the same app.

Is it normal behavior by design or is my app broken in some weird way? What should be the reliable procedure to give the app permissions to all secret versions, including also the future ones?

Answer (score 1):

> What should be the reliable procedure to give the app permissions to> all secret versions, including also the future ones?

AFAIK if we configure above scenario like below it won't be an issue.
However, you can share the code of your app so that I can check if anything has to be changed or not.

**I have tried below method to retrieve secrets from Azure key vault and it worked for me.**

**Step 1:** Create azure app service with **.net 6** runtime.

**Step 2:** Enable **System assigned** managed identity and make note of **Object (principal) ID**.

[image]

**Step 3:** Add **access policies** in Azure key vault.
Navigate to access policies and click on **create** button.

[image]

Select required **permissions** and click next.

[image]

Paste the Object Id copied in step 2.

[image]
Click **Review + create**.

**Step 4:** Create secret and refer it in azure web app.

[image]

Next, navigate to web app > Configuration add secret key.

[image]

It will take 1-2 mins to ressolve the secret.

[image]

I have added a new secret version in my key vault and it got resolved in my Web App without error:-

Added new version:-

[image]
Below is the screenshot after adding new version of secret in key vault.
[image]

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question, the OP understands how it should work, your answer merely recreates what is typically expected to be the status quo.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to exclude all variables one by one, to start with a simple web app in a clean Azure environment, and deploy it manually. Maybe the issue is caused by something very specific in Active Directory or pipeline ARM templates or the app code itself (although it does not use Keyvault from code), and I'll have to exclude all that.

Comment: Ok, there's one more thing I don't see in your scenario - after you add the new version to the secret, you should make all the old versions disabled. Otherwise, the app will still use one of the enabled old versions. So, make only the current version enabled, then restart your app and check if it hasn't lost the reference access. But it seems, it's not enough to trigger the bug, I could not reproduce it on an empty app either, will need to experiment a lot.

Comment: @JustAMartin I don't think so it is mandatory to disable the older versions when new version is available. App service will automatically fetch the latest version as we are not specifying the version in the secret reference link.

Comment: @GoonaBabu  I assumed the same, but it did not work. Try a minimal .net6 Web app as Visual Studio creates, and add the code to the WeatherForecastController:
`[Route("check-kvar")]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CheckKvar([FromServices]IConfiguration configuration)
{
    var kvalue1 = configuration["TestSecret"];
    return Ok(new { kvalue1 });
}`
Publish it to Azure, test if the controller returns this value. Add new version in keyvault, restart the app and run the controller again. For me, it keeps returning the old value, even when I disable the old versions. It's frustrating.

Comment: Oh, I think I got affected by caching also: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/36650#issuecomment-1182925249 If it's true, then it's really ugly - we cannot rely on switching keyvault values quickly, we have to do this dance with editing it to clear the cache. This explains the old versions getting stuck, but does not explain the access issue though.